# Matlab: Rejection sampling

Tags: matlab, random, sampling

I want to sample from only the tails ([-5sigma,-3sigma] and [3sigma,5sigma]) of a Normal Distribution when I run a Monte-Carlo Simulation and therefore Rejection Sampling comes to mind. I am however, struggling to implement this in Matlab. Up till now I have been using something similar to the code below (which I know isn't rejection sampling), but would Rejection Sampling be a better way to solve this issue?

```
function [new_E11] = elasticmodulusrng()

new_E11 = normrnd(136e9,9.067e9,[1 1]);

while new_E11>=136e9-3*9.067e9 && new_E11<=136e9+3*9.067e9
        new_E11 = normrnd(136e9,9.067e9,[1 1]);
end
```

Thanks

Edit: Using code in the Answer
[image]

Comment: The code below is rejection sampling, only for a different condition. btw: Avoid magic numbers. Assign your constants (`136e9` and `9.067e9`) to variables, which makes the code much easier to read and maintain.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks. Is there a way of increasing the _probability_ of selecting a number from the tails, rather than purely rejecting samples not from the tails?

Comment: @user131983 I don't think there is a say to do that. At least not an easy one.

Comment: The cdf of your distribution is known, the parts of the `normcdf` between [-5sigma,-3sigma] and [3sigma,5sigma] normalized to a integral of 1. Symbolic toolbox available?

Comment: @Daniel Yeah, I think that's a good idea. Normalising the tails so that their areas are equal to 1. Unfortunately, I do not have the Symbolic Toolbox though.

Answer (score 1):

```
mu=0
sigma=1
%get scaling factor
scale=(normcdf(5*sigma+mu,mu,sigma)-normcdf(3*sigma+mu,mu,sigma))*2
%define pdf
cpdf=@(x)((1/scale)*normpdf(x,mu,sigma).*((abs(x-mu)<5.*sigma)&(abs(x-mu.*sigma)>3)))
%get cdf via integral
ccdf=@(x)integral(cpdf,mu-5.*sigma,x)
%allow vector inputs
ccdf=@(x)arrayfun(ccdf,x)

%inverse cdf
icdf=@(y)(fzero(@(x)(ccdf(x)-y),.5));
%allow vector inputs    
icdf=@(x)arrayfun(icdf,x);
%icdf is very slow, thus evaluate some numbers and use the cached and interpolated version:
cachedicdf=nan(n+1,1);
x=0:0.01:1;
y=icdf(x);
icdf=@(uni)interp1(x,y,uni);
%plot some example data
hist(icdf(rand(10000000,1)),1000);
```

The accuracy is not what I expected, but I'll leave it here. Maybe someone is able to improve the code.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand what the code means, but I was just wondering how I should invert the cdf? Also, if I may ask, why is this necessary?

Comment: If you have the inverse CDF (lets call it icdf), `icdf(rand(n,m))` is a random sample of your distribution.

Comment: Thanks again. And just to check, this will have no bearing on the other interval (-3*sigma, 3*sigma) of the Normal Distribution? It will just be that the areas of the tails will now be 1 and that of the other interval will remain as 0.682 approx?

Comment: @user131983: I don't really understand your comment. Where does the `0.682` come from? I tried to finish it, but realised that I'm not very good at finding numerical solutions, the accuracy is not what I expected. Probably because I'm using mupad (symbolic math) since school days...

Comment: Thanks again. I was just wondering if you think I could use this whilst _also_ selecting data samples from (-3*sigma, 3*sigma)? That way, there will be a higher _probability_ of selecting from the tails which was the initial aim.

Comment: @user131983: For `(-3*sigma, 3*sigma)` I would use thinning because only very few samples get rejected.

Comment: Thank you. I'm sorry I'm being a bit daft but what do you mean by _thinning_? Also, from your answer, can't I just use this part of the code:  `x=0:0.01:1;
y=icdf(x);
icdf=@(uni)interp1(x,y,uni);
hist(icdf(rand(10000000,1)),1000);` It seems do the job. Thanks.